# How to stop using the arrow keys in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, vim-plugin

When I am using letter keys and move to arrow keys it's a waste of my time. For that, I use vim in vscode but problem is that I don't use h,j,k,l, etc letter when type. For example: when I type "j" my cursor down but I don't type the letter "j" ..how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to [touchcursor-linux](https://github.com/donniebreve/touchcursor-linux). It basically provides arrow keys and other button functionalities by making space button work as shift. I think it's really intutive and easy....and you don't have to switch to vim keyboard layout as well.